# "and little use on their legs"?

Tags: grammar

> Down the dwarves scrambled or jumped or dropped, eleven all in a heap, most of them very shaky and little use on their legs.

This I read in *The Hobbit*. I'm confused. Should it not be:

> Down the dwarves scrambled or jumped or dropped, eleven all in a heap, most of them very shaky and having little use of their legs.

Or:

> Down the dwarves scrambled or jumped or dropped, eleven all in a heap, most of them very shaky and with little use of their legs.

?

Comment: Do you seriously think that Tolkien would make a mistake like that?

Comment: @BillJ I have no idea. I've seen some pretty bizarre sentences so far, oftentimes related to leaving out commas and whatnot, so why not? Besides, I'm asking what he means by it -- not merely stating for a fact that he made a mistake.

Comment: Yes, it's unusual. Your paraphrases make sense. But 'little use on their legs' is closer to '[of] little use in an imminent fight [and unable to take immediate flight] because of their semi-paralysed legs'. Tolkien was the master of a punchy (perhaps boundary-pushing) turn of phrase.

Comment: @HarshdeepKrismer No, in your question you did not ask what he means, but whether the phrase in question should have been expressed some other way. FYI, Tolkien's wording is both syntactically and semantically impeccable.

Comment: @BillJ You could perhaps give some examples of parallels to 'little use on their legs' to back up your statement.

Comment: Where is this scene, by the way?

Comment: Editors sometimes miss things. That's what this sounds like to me. The only difference between **of** and **on** is one letter and it's the kind of mistake that is easily missed.

Comment: After reading it a couple of times (given no context), I think it means that their legs were not used much during the scrambling/jumping/dropping. i.e. it was falling more than running. Something "has little use on it" if it was not used much.

Comment: @BillJ well, a typesetter could too, and it could be missed in proof copies (though I don't believe it to be the case)

Comment: @Lambie That's a reasonable supposition, but it has survived numerous re-editions. I'm not a Tolkien scholar, but he was meticulous about language (and certainly would fight to defend any "edge-case" use he might fancy), and while I don't doubt that the initial edition might have contained errors, I imagine he was motivated to find and correct them in subsequent ones. Plus, if we change it to "of," we do have to add a word.

Comment: In what context is this sentence? Is there some reason why their lack of coordination might be especially noteworthy (poisoned by spiders, long imprisonment, exhaustion) as opposed to just a jab at dwarfish clumsiness in general?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It **is little use** giving examples each one of which will fill a comments box. It **is equally little use** attempting to improve Tolkien's English - he was Merton Professor of English Language and Literature.

Comment: @Greybeard It is little use arguing from analogy; 'It is equally little use attempting to improve Tolkien's English' does not fully license '{most of them} [being] ... little use on their legs'. It's also invidious insinuating that a person might just be attempting to improve Tolkien's English. I'd say he is virtually in the Shakespeare class, and that gives a fair degree of licence. But this makes it difficult to match all usages with those going before.

Answer (score 13):

This is not a verb, but "use" as a noun, meaning "usefulness." [This Merriam-Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/use), in the noun section, definition 2C, gives the example "*it's no use arguing*", and links to GOOD sense 2b, "*something useful or beneficial*."

In this sense, we might say to someone "Oh, you're no use." The quote comes as the dwarves face an attack; their "usefulness" for fighting is the focus. The surrounding context discusses their semi-paralysis and their readiness for a fight.

Comment: Hello Andy, you seem to be newish. Welcome aboard. That said, this Q sounds like it would be a better fit at SciFi.SE, or possibly Literature.SE

Comment: @Cascabel Or ELL; it is at core a question about a usage rather than literary interpretation (and a simple enough usage, though I don't fault the OP for having a hard time hunting down a less-common usage of a very-common word). I maybe shouldn't have gone on so much about the context, though it does help narrow down the usage here.

Comment: ...yeah..it is usage, but is so localized and specific that the best analysis would come from Literature.SE or maybe SciFi.SE...You have racked up an impressive rep, and I appreciate your drive...but this interpretation probably belongs elsewhere.

Comment: so I am taking responsibility for casting the closing vote...I did not DV

Comment: @Cascabel it's a reasonable ELU question.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, it is a reasonable question, just not here. It sounds like LitCrit believe  me, this was a difficult call.. I am definitely in the camp that would like to widen our horizons, but I am not sure this is our place to declare new linguistic boundaries

Comment: @Cascabel No it's not litcrit at all. They're asking a question about how to parse that phrase.

Comment: What confuses me about this interpretation is that it implies comparison to something else. For instance, "Penguins can move quite gracefully in water, but are of little use on land". Is the use of dwarves on their legs being compared to them, say, being on their hands and knees?

Comment: I think it could be a comparison to other races/species/people, rather than to how useful they are in other media. Dwarfs are little use on their feet, unlike elves.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes. I removed some discussion of the context since it seems to be causing some concern, but it mentions one of the dwarves having to be propped up. Tolkien is of course not implying that they're of *more* use semi-paralyzed, but that their legs are needed eminently.

Comment: @Mitch Fair enough...but I am still not convinced this belongs here. As several well-respected users here have said, Tolkien was a master of the language, and it is improbable he made a mistake. If it were actually a mistake, it might make a good paper at under-grad level, but to the contrary, it is very likely it was a publishing error...

Comment: In the meantime, I'm gonna blow the dust off of my ancient copy and sneeze my way through to the appropriate chapter.

Comment: This isn't Tolkien's fault; it's the fault of the orthography. _Use_ the verb is pronounced /yuz/ but _use_ the noun is pronounced /yus/. And they're both spelled the same, so if you don't twig to the pronunciation difference, you think (correctly) that that's an incorrect use of the verb, but don't notice that it's a correct use of the noun.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you mind if I turn that along with BillJ comment  into a Wiki answer?

Comment: I think we're all happy with 'This stick/Jim is [of] little use in a fight', 'umbrellas are [of] little use in a gale' and perhaps even 'He was little use on a horse' (very few Google hits for this). The activity there is little fitness for is easily retrievable. But 'little use on their legs' seems boundary-pushing. There are very few hits on Google for a << "little use on their legs" -Hobbit >> search.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Andy Bonner's post, but would like to contribute the following, as links often decay over time....

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> This isn't Tolkien's fault; it's the fault of the orthography. *Use* the verb is pronounced /yuz/ but *use* the noun is pronounced /yus/. And they're both spelled the same, so if you don't twig to the pronunciation difference, you think (correctly) that that's an incorrect use of the verb, but don't notice that it's a correct use of the noun.

Also, BillJ wrote:

> Do you seriously think that Tolkien would make a mistake like that?

And  Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> Yes, it's unusual. Your paraphrases make sense. But 'little use on their legs' is closer to '[of] little use in an imminent fight [and unable to take immediate flight] because of their semi-paralysed legs'. Tolkien was the master of a punchy (perhaps boundary-pushing) turn of phrase.